# Firebase multi location update handles security rules differently?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**EDIT:** Figured it out. Multi-location updates work not like updates as far as they seem to overwrite pre-existing values.

I have a hard time figuring out security rules for multi location updates. Until now I had this code

```
return this.userProfileRef.child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).update(profileData);
```

to update a user profile in fb, where `profileData` is an object containing some fields.

when I try to do the same operation, but written in a way that I can add more write operations (multi-location update), I get a validation error.

```
var updateData = {};
updateData['users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid] = profileData;
return firebase.database().ref().update(updateData);
```

my security rules are

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": "true",
    ".read": "true",
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "!data.exists() || ( data.exists() && auth.uid === $uid )",
        "profileStatus": {
          ".validate": "!data.exists() || (newData.parent().hasChildren(['firstName', 'dateOfBirth', 'gender', 'lookingForGender', 'lookingForAgeMin', 'lookingForAgeMax', 'lookingForRadius']) && data.val() === 'incomplete' && newData.val() === 'awaitingVerification')"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Validation fails in profileStatus, when I do the multi-location update as written above, but passes when I do a 'normal' update.

Can someone help out and tell me what I'm missing here. Does fb handle multi-location updates differently when it comes to security rules?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to answer my own question. It seems that multi-loation update works more like a multi-lcoation set, so it overwrites existing values which caused my validation fail.

I'm still confused by this beviour… following the firebase blog here I thought, it would wor like an update.

In my example, i have a pre-existing key called dateOfBirth. This key gets deletd when I run the multi-update